# WPF Custom Control can not take direct content

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, contentpresenter

I can't put any direct content in my custom control, have a look:

```
    <Style TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">    
         <Setter Property="Template">           
            <Setter.Value>              
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyCustomControl">
                    <Grid>                  
                        <Viewport3D />                      
                        <!-- the viewport is working (proof provided) -->
                        <!-- both borders are needed -->

                        <Border>
                            <Border>                               
                                <ContentPresenter  />    
                            </Border>
                        </Border>                   
                    </Grid>             
                </ControlTemplate>              
            </Setter.Value>         
        </Setter>    
    </Style>
```

the class is derived from *Control*, in the static constructor `DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata` is set.

When I try to use MyCustomControl:

```
    <local:MyCustomControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="16" Text="some test value" />
    </local:MyCustomControl>
```

this error message is shown:

> Cannot add content to object of type MyCustomControl
>   MyNamespace.MyCustomControl

What could be the problem? Is somthing wrong with the Contentpresenter?

Answer (score -14, accepted):

Thanks ZerO, this was an excellent hint:

MyCustomControl derived from *Control* - now it derives from **ContenControl**.
After changing the base class I am now able to bind like suggested by ZerO.

```
<ContentPresenter  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
```

problem solved!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. You can mark the answer as Correct Answer if you want.

Comment: The accepted answer should mention the changed base class, which was the actual problem. After changing to ContentControl, you could even omit `Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"` and just write `<ContentPresenter/>`. The Content Binding is done implicitly. So better accept your own answer. The other one gave you a hint, but did not actually solve your problem.

Comment: Well basically there is a fb post about this SE post that explains the downvotes: https://www.facebook.com/100064769106555/posts/pfbid0RU4t9A7Ga6zyypCwLhFUu44SzzriJBHHTQEsDrrsBUutCT4JWME7CohU7ZFsuMkNl/

Answer (score 69):

I think you should bind your Content to your Presenter

```
<ContentPresenter  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
```